# Is the conjecture true? $3^n - 2^m = 1$ has infinitely many solutions, where n, m are natural numbers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures

Is the conjecture true?

$3^n - 2^m = 1 $ has infinitely many solutions, where n, m are natural numbers.

More generally,
$P^n-Q^m=1$ has infinitely many solution for n, m ϵ {1,2,3,…} where P is odd, Q is even, P and Q have no common factors.

$P^n-Q^m=2$ has infinitely many solution for n, m ϵ {1,2,3,…} where P, Q  are both odd, P and Q have no common factors.

This is my first post - I joined this community to look into this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: See the [Catalan conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), which was proven in 2002.

Comment: Well, what have you done so far? What solutions have you found so far? If there are infinitely many, there is probably some pattern. So find some!

Comment: Thank you. I'd mark the Catalan conjecture as answering my question. But I don't see how.

Comment: There is only ONE pair of consecutive perfect powers  (if we exclude $0$ and $1$) , namely $8$ and $9$. This has been proven in the mean time, for other differences the problem is open (See Pillai's conjecture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mihăilescu's theorem, before 2002 known as Catalan's conjecture, states that:

> The only natural numbers $m,n>1$ and $P,Q>0$ satisfying $$P^n-Q^m=1,$$are $(m,n,P,Q)=(2,3,3,2)$.